# MATLAB .m file to mex file conversion

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-deployment

I have a MATLAB program which I need to call from php. I converted it into an exe with the help of deploytool but it is too slow. So I want to convert it into a mex file or a C file then to a exe so that the execution time speeds up. What is the best method to do this?I looked at the MATLAB coder but I don't think so it supports my program. So any method to convert the matlab .m file to mex file executable?

I want a method that speeds up my execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that mere [converting](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/matlab-coder/) a .m file to .mex then compiling would speed up your program (mind that you'd still need the MCR installed). Maybe, depending on the problem and the skill of the programmer, *re-implementing* some of it from scratch would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A .mex file is compiled C code with an interface to allow you to call it from MATLAB. It is not compiled .m MATLAB code.

If you want to convert your MATLAB code to C for speedup, you can use MATLAB Coder if it supports your code, or reimplement if not. Note that it might be possible that it supports some of your code, and you could reimplement the rest.